# how to echo the prepared SQL statement from a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I am working on a project that involves PHP and SQL.
I am trying to understand a PHP function that updates something on the MySQL database:

```
<?php
function save_profile($player, $args) {
        global $pdo;
        $params = ["player"=>$player];
        $setStr = "";
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
                $setStr .= $key . "=" . $pdo->quote($value) . ",";
        }
        $setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE players SET $setStr WHERE username = :player");
        $stmt -> execute($params);
        echo $stmt;
}
?>
```

I am trying to see what the resulting SQL queries look like?

I tried to pass in two values and print it would like this:

> save_profile('john', 'hello');

But it failed with the following error:

> PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object

I am not sure where to pass the array.
Or what parameters to pass to the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, type given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/77934648#77934648)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am not sure what to pass to the function. What parameters do the function take. That is my question.

Comment: With respect, @stacflo, the question you have posted here is clear from the title: how to echo a prepared query. If you think you've asked some different question then you need to clarify exactly what you are asking by editing the question.

Comment: You're using PDO, good, but that is not how you use it. I'd try to build a SET clause that looks like `SET foo = :foo, bar = :bar` followed by two calls to bindValue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try like this**

```
<?php
function save_profile($player, $args) {
        global $pdo;
        $params = ["player"=>$player];
        $setStr = "";
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
                $setStr .= $key . "=" . "'$value'" . ",";
        }
        $setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE players SET $setStr WHERE username = :player");
        $stmt -> execute($params);
        //echo $stmt;
}

$array = array(
"table_column_name_1" => "Value which is you want to update",
"table_column_name_2" => "Value which is you want to update"
);
save_profile('john', $array);
?>
```

Comment: It results in this error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function quote()

Comment: I have just edited the above code, please try it.

Comment: Why perpetuate the fundamental error in the SQL? This is still potentially wide open to SQL injection as per the original!